# Habilitar GPS dentro da aplicação

Tags: java, android, gps

Atualmente para verificar se o GPS está habilitado uso o seguinte código:

```
public boolean checkSetting(){
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

Retornando falso é lançado um dialogo no qual é usado um `Intent` para direcionar o usuário para a tela de configurações do GPS. Veja a intenção:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Percebi que no aplicativo do Google Maps não precisa sair da tela para que o GPS seja habilitado. Da mesma forma é lançado um diálogo porém, neste mesmo diálogo, ao clicar em habilitar, logo o GPS é habilitado. Pensei que talvez seria um privilégio do Google Maps por ser do próprio Google, mas talvez não.

Como habilitar GPS dentro da aplicação, sem entrar na tela de configurações?

Comment: Fazer aquele com popup perguntando ao usuário, parece que é possivel sim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29744737/5524514 e http://stackoverflow.com/a/29697889/5524514

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que eu saiba a única possibilidade é usar a [SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) da Google, que julgo que é o que o aplicativo Google Maps usa.

A API permite de forma fácil uma aplicação garantir/verificar se as definições do dispositivo estão configuradas para as necessidades dela.

Comece por obter um SettingsClient

```
SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
```

Crie depois um LocationSettingsRequest.Builder e adicione todos os  LocationRequests que a aplicação necessitar:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestHighAccuracy)
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);
```

Verifique se as definições do dispositivo estão configuradas para satisfazer aquelas requeridas pelo LocationSettingsRequest:

```
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
```

O resultado da verificação pode ser obtido nos *listener* atribuídos ao Task:

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        // Todas as definições do dispositivo estão configuradas para satisfazer as requeridas. 
        // Pode iniciar os pedidos de localização aqui.
        // ...
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
        switch (statusCode) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // As definições do dispositivo não satisfazem as requeridas.
                //Mas podem ser alteradas pelo utilizador.
                try {
                    // Mostra um dialog chamando startResolutionForResult(),
                    // o resultado deverá ser verificado em onActivityResult().
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                    // Ignore o erro.
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // As definições do dispositivo não satisfazem as requeridas, não havendo forma de as resolver.
                // Nenhum dialog será mostrado.
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Se as definições do dispositivo não satisfazem as requeridas e estas podem ser alteradas pelo usuário(LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED), um dialog é mostrado. O resultado é recebido no método `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);
     switch (requestCode) {
         case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
             switch (resultCode) {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     // Todas as alterações necessárias foram feitas
                     ...
                     break;
                 case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                     // O usuário cancelou o dialog, não fazendo as alterações requeridas
                     ...
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
             }
             break;
     }
 }
```

**Nota:**

Esta abordagem não garante que o GPS seja ligado.
A fonte ou fontes a utilizar(GPS, WI-FI ou rede móvel) para obter a localização são escolhidas em função do LocationSettingsRequest definido.
Um LocationRequest com uma prioridade de `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` poderá não ligar o GPS caso tenha disponível outra fonte que garanta a precisão requerida - cerca de 10 Km.

Referências:

- [Changing Location Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html).
- [SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient).

Comment: `mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy` é o modo apenas gps?

Comment: @diegofm `mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy` é um objecto do tipo [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)  que serve para definir a "qualidade" do serviço de localização. A "qualidade" é definida por vários valores sendo os mais importantes o intervalo de actualização e a prioridade. PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY é uma constante a ser usada em `setPriority()` que define uma precisão de mais ou menos 100 metros.

Comment: @diegofm O código que usei na resposta é da documentação, que neste caso o uso dos nomes dos atributos `mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy` e `mLocationRequestHighAccuracy` não fazem muito sentido já que sugerem dois tipos de precisão diferentes

Comment: Encontrei uma solução bem próxima da sua resposta, porém explicando um pouco mais sobre o `LocationRequest`. Vou validar a resposta, mas depois se quiser incrementar o `LocationRequest` melhorará o entendimento para outras pessoas. Abs. Obrigado.

Comment: Em que termos? Note que explicar o que é o LocationRequest não é o foco da pergunta. Ele é apenas um meio necessário para obter aquele dialog. Talvez um nova pergunta fosse mais proveitosa.

Comment: Adicionei uma nota relacionada com o LocationRequest que é relevante para a pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral legal... realmente eu não sabia desta questão da bateria. Obrigado.