# Pegar a localização do usuário sem usar GPS

Tags: android, gps

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no android que é preciso notificar um grupo de usuários que se encontram numa determinada região. A única forma que eu conheço de pegar a localização do usuário é usando o GPS.

O problema é que para ativar/desativar o gps é preciso a aprovação do usuário, com isso, já não será possível notificar em uma determinada região.

Como que eu posso resolver este problema?, quais são as possíveis técnicas útil para esta situação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O GPS não é o único meio para obter a localização do usuário. Ela pode ser obtida por WI-FI ou rede móvel(triangulação de antenas). No entanto, a sua precisão pode ser baixa para o que pretende.

A API para a obter a localização, em função da disponibilidade e dos requisitos indicados, usa o meio mais adequado.

Se estiver a utilizar o [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) os requisitos são indicados através de um objecto LocationRequest:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
```

O meio ou meios a utilizar para obter a localização são escolhidas em função do LocationRequest definido.
Um LocationRequest com uma prioridade de PRIORITY_LOW_POWER poderá não usar o GPS caso tenha disponível outra fonte que garanta a precisão requerida - cerca de 10 Km.

Assim sendo não há nada que você possa fazer. Se o usuário não permitir ligar o GPS a API não o poderá utilizar.
No entanto a localização continuará a poder ser obtida por outro meio disponível(se houver algum) mas com uma precisão menor.

Vejas estas perguntas para mais detalhe.

- [Como obter a localização atual do dispositivo android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541)
- [Habilitar GPS dentro da aplicação.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199738/2541)
- [Gps ou triangulação de antenas - Como saber a precisão da localização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124462/2541)

**Nota** Qualquer que seja o meio utilizado a aplicação necessitará sempre da permissão `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` ou `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.